# Entering 2d array elements row by row without knowing the number of rows

Tags: java, arrays

```
       public static double[][] get2DArrayInput(int array1DLength) {
       Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Please enter the data for the two-dimensional array.");
       int rows;
       System.out.print("Please enter the number of columns of the 2D array: ");
       int columns = stdin.nextInt();
       double[][] twoDArray = new double[columns][];
       do {
       System.out.println("Please enter the array elements by rows: ");
       for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[i].length; j++) {
               twoDArray[i][j] = stdin.nextDouble();
           }
       }
       rows = twoDArray[0].length;
       if (array1DLength != rows) {
           System.out.println("Sorry, please ensure that the number of rows of the 2D array" +
                    " matches the length of the 1D array.");
       }
       } while (array1DLength != rows);

       return twoDArray;
   }
```

I'm trying to enter the rows of the 2D array row-by-row without knowing the number of rows. I'm messing something up with the for loops, but I'm uncertain of what it is. Would it be better to just use a single for loop instead of nested for loops?

Comment: I'll assume you're working within some sort of constraint which dictates the data structure you use, but why would you resort to using arrays when you don't know the number of rows? An ArrayList or other adaptable list might be a better solution. That being said, it appears you're trying to execute a for-loop using the length of an array that doesn't have an explicit size, so it's always coming back 0 length

Comment: Why use "array1DLength" as a parameter?

Comment: @Sentimental It's from my main method, I'm trying to write a program that does matrix multiplication and I need to ensure that the number of rows of the 2D array match the number of columns of a 1D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't created the arrays at each index of the original array.

Instead of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[i].length; j++) {
        twoDArray[i][j] = stdin.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of rows: ");
    int numrows = stdin.nextDouble();
    twoDArray[i] = new double[numrows];  // need to initialize the array first

    System.out.println("Please enter the array elements by rows: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[i].length; j++) {
        twoDArray[i][j] = stdin.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

I'll recommend that a solution where you don't know the end-size of the data structure utilize one that can change dynamically, such as `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize the number of **rows** and **columns** in this scenario. An array is a fixed amount of size and cannot be changed dynamically

Use ArrayList on java instead.... You can keep on adding or deleting... the size can be changed dynamically

ex:-

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("String"); // adds a string value in this case
```

so your answer would be

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> group = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>(); // array list of array list
```